# Is there any plans for the graphical layout of the web site?

Tags: discussion

Is there any plans for the graphical layout of the web site when it will get out of beta phase ?

Comment: Once SE decides that we're ready to go out of beta Jin, the designer working for SE, usually posts some ideas on the site meta and asks for some feedback and additional ideas. We also have [a question about design ideas](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/352/design-ideas-for-skeptics) already which was posted in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Sites get their designs when they graduate out of beta, so I'm assuming that your question is equivalent to "When will we graduate?"

Here are some of [this site's statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics), and here's [how it compares to other sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true). Along with those, I also strongly recommend reading the blog posts [When will my site graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) and [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

My personal reccomendation: more questions and more answers, please!

Comment: The number of questions dropped when we started to explicitly require notable claims, which was pretty much initiated by Jeff (see [this post](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-notable-does-a-claim-have-to-be-for-questions-about-it-to-be-considered-on-t/808#808)). I agree that the number of answers could be higher, but with our citation requirements answers here are often a lot more work than on other sites, I think we'll always be lagging in that aspect behind other SE sites.

Comment: @Fabian I concur. Furthermore, our site has a very high signal-to-noise ratio because the answers are, by large and by far, well researched. We achieve that by discouraging bad quality answers, or, in other words, by having less answers. Therefore the answer ratio parameter actually works against quality for us and should be discounted.